# javascript setAttribute iframe allowfullscreen doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, iframe, leaflet

I have a map in an iframe (Chrome 67.0.3396.87). E.g.

```
<iframe height="480px" 
src="http://brunob.github.io/leaflet.fullscreen/" 
width="450px">
</iframe>
```

The CMS we use strips out the `allowfullscreen` attribute from the iframe, so I'm trying to inject them back in using Javascript.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].getAttribute("src") == "http://brunob.github.io/leaflet.fullscreen/" ? document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].setAttribute("allowFullScreen", ""):null;
```

This changes the DOM, but the fullscreen button doesn't work. However, if you start with the iframe and `allowfullscreen` set, then it does work.

```
<iframe height="480px" 
src="http://brunob.github.io/leaflet.fullscreen/" 
width="450px" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

How do I get the change in the DOM to register, it should be automatic?!

- UPDATE: This works in IE 11
- UPDATE: This works in Firefox 60.0.1

Comment: Have you tried settings it as `setAttribute( 'allowFullScreen', true )` instead of empty string?

Comment: Yes, no luck, with quotes and without quotes

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/5d8010e1fc081481d0646618e700b51a4699ab4c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a *feature* of Chrome, [not present in other browsers](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=853178), that you must update the iframe content before the allowfullscreen button kicks in. You can work around it by first loading the HTML with the iframe, then running the script:

```
<iframe height="480px" 
src="http://brunob.github.io/leaflet.fullscreen/" 
width="450px">
</iframe>

<script>
// add allowfullscreen attribute to the iframe
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].getAttribute("src") == "https://interact.bcs.org/tracer/1/BCS_point_map.html" ? document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].setAttribute("allowFullScreen", true):null;

// refresh the iframe container
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src
</script>
```